# How to update image(file_get_contents)?

Tags: php, mysqli

I created this code to save the photo and create folder by month and save it to my database mysql.

```
    <?php
include 'connect.php';
$name = $_POST['name'];
$date1 = date('Ymd');
$month = date('Ymd');
$photo_file = 'photo/'.$month.'/'.$date1."".$name.".jpg";
echo $photo_file;
$encoded_data = $_POST['mydata'];
$binary_data = base64_decode( $encoded_data );
    // save to server (beware of permissions)
if (!is_dir('photo/' . $month)) {
  // dir doesn't exist, make it
  mkdir('photo/' . $month);
}
    $result = file_put_contents($photo_file, $binary_data);
    $sql="INSERT INTO image (images) VALUES('$photo_file')";
    $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);    

?>
```

the problem is how to update(replace with a new one) the current save photo? What approach should I use to update it?